# Using OpenCover to run Coded UI tests not collecting Application Code

Tags: coded-ui-tests, opencover

We have a windows client that our QA team wrote coded UI tests for. I'm trying to get OpenCover to work so we can see how much of the app their tests are really hitting. They wrote their tests using a custom framework on top of the MSTest framework.

Their framework uses ApplicationUnderTest.Launch to start the application as different users to test security settings. I can capture coverage of the test dlls but the application it self.

I've forced the app to build in 32bit, made sure all pdbs are present in the folders and included the pdb directory in the targetdir as well.

Has anyone else seen this issue? I also tried replacing my batch file with a wrapper exe and got coverage for that but not the main application. Everything is running as the user they are starting the application as who is also an admin on the machine.

The command I'm running is: 
C:\Users\kkindt.CORP\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register "-target:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" -output:C:\CodeCoverage\CollectionResults\CodedUICover.xml "-targetargs:C:\CodeCoverage\Tests\EllisWinAppTest.dll /Platform:x86 /Framework:framework40 /Tests:LaunchEllisTest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect it is due to how you are launching the application under test

OpenCover is a .NET profiler and for .NET application to be launched with a profiler attached requires some environment variables to be available to the new process. I suspect that `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch` does not propagate all the current environment variables and so the profiler does not start and therefore does not report coverage.

To get this to work you should look into using the [ApplicationUnderTest.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419605.aspx) overload that uses a ProcessStartInfo and then you need to propagate the following environment variables

- Cor_Profiler
- Cor_Enable_Profiling
- OpenCover_Profiler_Key
- OpenCover_Profiler_Namespace
- OpenCover_Profiler_Threshold
- OpenCover_Profiler_TraceByTest (if available)

The `Cor_*` are required by the runtime to launch a profiler and the `OpenCover_*` entries are to allow the profiler and the host to find each other - a [list of these environment variables](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/blob/master/main/OpenCover.Framework/Manager/ProfilerManager.cs#L83) are available on github

Comment: you sir, are the man. added a loop to propagate the variables to the launch process and it collected just fine. Thanks for you help!

Comment: nice - I am wondering whether it could be added to OpenCover to automatically inject that information if not already there - could be a nice feature

Comment: @Kevin - I am looking to add this to OpenCover but having trouble repeating your issue would you [possibly enagage](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/244) with us to make this a seemless integration?